# Plot every n series of a vector until end of data | python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, matplotlib

I found many examples to plot every n elements of a vector, but I could not find to plot every n elements (plural) of a vector. My initial vector has xaxis from 1 to 15768000, which is 5 years in seconds, while yaxis are the measurements. Length of the vector is 15768000. I need to plot data every 24 hours or in this case every 86400 values (24 hours in seconds).

For example:

```
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

How can I plot every 3 elements 1,2,3 then 4,5,6 from the beginning and 7,8,9 from the beginning.

New xaxis for my case should be from 1 to 86400. How can I modify the values of the vector to be plotted every 86400 values from the beginning all over until the end of data? For my case I would have 1825 scenarios on the plot (vector with every 86400 for 5 years). Figure below shows what I am trying to achieve (in this example every 15 hours is plotted).

[image: Figure]

Comment: do you have a numpy array, pd.Series, list?

Comment: @ansev i have measurements in a list

Answer (score 0):

### updated answer:

I believe you just need to reshape your data prior plotting...

```
days = 20
pts = 86400
m = np.random.rand(pts*days)-0.5

m = np.reshape(m,(pts,days))

m = 1+np.cumsum(m,axis=0)
plt.plot(m)
```

[image]

### old answer:

There are various ways to subsample, downsample. Simplest way is to just plot data point for every x-th element, which I believe is what you desire "need to plot data every 24 hours or in this case every 86400 values". To do that you simply can plot every x-th data point, example code is shown below.

Example 1. without using pandas.

```
# import 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
```

```
# generate random data
m = np.random.rand(10000,10)-0.5
m = 1+np.cumsum(m,axis=0)
```

```
# plot every x-th element
skip = 1000 # every 1000!
for x in range(10):
    plt.scatter(np.arange(0,10000,skip),m[::skip,x])
plt.plot(m,alpha=0.5)
plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

Example 2. with Pandas (my preference).

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# form dataframe object
df = pd.DataFrame(m)
# add hypothetical time
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(10000)]
df.index = date_list
```

```
#plot data with and without skipping
df.iloc[::skip,].plot()
```

[image]

```
df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer  @teng , although I am not able to achieve what I need. In my scenario, I need to plot every 86400 values from beginning to end, which would represent one day, and one line. First day is 0 to 86400, and one line. Furthermore, second line (or second day) would again start from the beginning of the x axis, but continuing the vector, meaning from 86400 to 172000 (86400+86400 or second day), third line 172000 to 172000+86400 (third day). The range of my data is 15768000, but I need x axis of 86400, not 15768000...

Comment: I see @robmiller505 i think you just need to reshape your data before plotting. checkout my updated answer.

Comment: thanks @teng. after reading my data and applying your approach `m = np.reshape(m,(pts,years))`, where for years I put 365*5 (days*years), and I get the following issue: cannot reshape array of size 157680001 into shape (86400,1825). My data has shape (157680001,1) . Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: @robmiller505 86400*1825=157680000, your raw data have one additional data point! find that one extra point and get rid of it. `m = np.reshape(m[1:],(pts,years))`.